# How do I make a JQuery Progress Bar in Backbone show progress for multiple Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, progress-bar

Edit:

I can't even get a simple setup working with backbone js such that in the controller

```
initialize: function() {

    // alert("1"); 
    $( "#progressbar" ).html("0%");
    // alert("2");

    $.ajax({
      dataType:"json", 
      async:true,
      url:"http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list",
      success: function(data, response) {

      }
    });


    // alert("3");
    $( "#progressbar" ).html("25%");
            // it works when i put the alerts in...

},
```

any ideas?

---

I am trying to place a jquery progress bar upon loading. My current structure is java and backbone.

When i come into the backbone controller, I want to initialise the progress bar, and after each ajax call update the value like the following

```
    initialize: function() {

    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ 
        value: 0
    });

    var tasks = $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      url: "http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list",
      success:function(data,response) {
        tsks = data;
      }
    });

    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ 
        value: 50
    });

    var tasks2 = $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      url: "http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list2",
      success:function(data,response) {
        tsks = data;
      }
    });

    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ 
        value: 100
    });
```

In my index.html i have  
But the progress bar does not show at all.....unless i wrap alerts around each $progress bar update....

In my backend java i am running the thread sleep for testing purposes...

if i put alerts around each progress bar update in the above, it works... i am not sure how this is happening... any ideas how to fix this

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet

Answer (score 0):

Your progressbar code needs to go inside the `success` function

```
var tasks = $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      url: "http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list",
      success:function(data,response) {
        tsks = data;
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ 
          value: 50
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: hi thanks but is there any reason why the original progress bar wont even show up at all unless i put alerts around it
`$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
   value: 0
  });` . when i put this before any function, this doesnt show up unless i put an alert on either side.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely caused by the fact that when you call `jQuery.ajax` with the `async:false` option, the AJAX call blocks the GUI thread for the duration of the  execution, so the browser can't update the progress bar. You should make your AJAX calls asynchronous, and update the progress bar after each step has succeeded:

The simple way:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ 
    value: 0
});

//make first call
var tasks = $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list",
  success:function(data,response) {

    //first call succeeded
    tsks = data;
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ 
        value: 50
    });

    //make second call
    var tasks2 = $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list2",
      success:function(data,response) {

        //second call succeeded
        tsks = data;
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ 
            value: 100
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This solution is far from perfect. It still makes the two AJAX requests sequentially, which is sub-optimal compared to making the requests concurrently. Maybe something like:

```
var $progressbar = $("#progressbar");
var progress = 0;
var updateProgress = function(amount) {
  $progressbar.progressbar({value:progress+=amount});
};

updateProgress(0);

$.ajax({
  dataType:"json", 
  url:"http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list",
  success: function(data, response) {
    updateProgress(50);
  }
});

$.ajax({
  dataType:"json", 
  url:"http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list2",
  success: function(data, response) {
    updateProgress(50);
  }
});
```

Comment: hi thanks but is there any reason why the original progress bar wont even show up at all unless i put alerts around it
`$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
   value: 0
  });` . when i put this before any function, this doesnt show up unless i put an alert on either side.

Comment: $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
   value: 0
  });

  $.ajax({
    dataType:"json", 
    async:true,
    url:"http://localhost:8888/chathau5/rest/tasks/list",
    success: function(data, response) {
    }
  });

Comment: @TylerEvans maybe the DOM hasn't yet initialized, so there's no `#progressbar` element?

Comment: but it works when i put alerts around each $("#progressbar")..blah :S

Comment: Could you explain why it's more optimal to load concurrently than sequentially?

Comment: @TylerEvans, it's a loading order issue. Either the `#progress` DOM element is not initialized when you first try to update it, or the GUI thread is being blocked by some synchronous javascript code. Either or, but I can't tell you which.

Comment: I will do whichever makes more sense. I am just trying to workout why I can't do $("#progress").html("0%");  and then $("#progress").html("25%"); etc in the backbone controller..it only shows in the dom if i alert before/after...

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, let's say the first request takes 50ms to complete, and the second takes 55ms. Sequentially that takes total 105ms, but concurrently (both requests running simultaneously) it only takes 55ms, the duration of the longer request.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And the fact that both requests are running simultaneously won't increase the length of the individual requests?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, as a general rule it won't. On the client side there might be *tiny* overhead, but definitely nothing measurable. Assuming your server can handle concurrent connections (as most do), that won't slow it down either.

Comment: hi i worked in out but not sure how to fix
when i look at the network panel in console chrome, it shows the controller.js return 304 status code (it doesn't show the progress), but when i add alert it... it returns 200 Modified status code and does show the progress... all the sources are being loaded in the correct order... so i guess.. how can i change it so that the controller.js returns a 200 ok status (from my code at the top) without using alert statements

Comment: Sorry to hijack the thread Tyler and thanks for your explanations fencliff. I'll leave you both to it now ;)

Comment: it seems like every time i place an alert in the controller.js file then i can see the % show up... else it just doesnt show:/

Comment: @TylerEvans, are you clearing away the progressbar, or overwriting it with something else? If you do, you must do that only after the requests have completed, i.e. after both of the `success` callbacks have fired. I'm really not able to help more with the information and code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

First, when something like an alert is helping, it's usually because you have a concurrency bug, meaning that something is finishing or not finishing before something else. They're really hard to detect. I would guess that the #progressbar is not actually on the screen when initialize gets called. I could do a quick console.log($("#progressbar")); on the first line of initialize, just to be sure it's actually there.

Secondly, this is something of an aside but it might help you understand how concurrency errors can take place. We have no guarantee that the first ajax call will finish first. That's the asynchronous nature of ajax, we give up control to our callbacks at that point and then we continue with the rest of the method. So your initialize method is probably finishing, before either of those two success methods get reached. For that reason it's best to nest the two calls.

```
// I like keeping my display code separated out like this.
this.updateProgress = function( newValue )
{
  $("#progressbar").progressBar({value:newValue}); 
}

$.ajax({ // first call
  success: function() // done loading when this gets called
  {
    this.updateProgress(50);
    $.ajax({ // second call
      success: function() // all done loading at this point
      {
        this.updateProgress(100);
      }  
    });
  }
});
```

That way, you can be sure that one loads after another. No reason not to do it at the same time like in your example, but this way we have a guarantee.